# Test status got changed to 'Outdated' in Quality Center. How to change to Ready?

Tags: quality-center

I deleted some Business components and consolidated tests in Quality center. Then I consolidated them again and created the Business components back. Now, the status of those testscripts got changed to Outdated. I checked each and every component in the script (right mouse click and go to the component) and they all exist. So don't know why it's outdated. Tried changing it to Ready status manually. But when I refresh, it changes back to Outdated.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Quality center has possibility to redefine the workflow of any group of records, therefore it is hard to say what you should do. Probably you do not have the possibility to change it, indicating you are not an administrator of the project, so you should ask your administrator what is next step in the workflow.

I can only guess, that the record has date of planned solution and this is not set to the future. You or your test manager should change something to unlock the constraint in your workflow.